# Native Web RTC Video Call freeze on Android when call from iOS app

Tags: android, ios, webrtc, h.264, vp9

We're implementing video calls on Android & iOS applications using WebRTC technology.

We also implemented on web browser and call successfully from chrome to android, and chrome to iOS.

But, when we call from iOS native to Android native, the video call always freeze after ~ 2 minutes. The Audio is still work, but the video stream freeze.

We researched this problem very hard, even we tried to modify SDP content of Offer & Answer as this Article described (https://medium.com/@fippo/when-a-browser-update-breaks-your-native-app-for-a-change-3845b30ea185).

We also thought maybe the cause of problem is H264 codecs of iOS, so we tried to replace VP9 to H264 in SDP content like the codes below, but no luck.

```
private String modifySdp(String sdp) {
    return sdp.replace("VP9/90000", "H264/90000\r\n"
            + "a=fmtp:101 profile-level-id=42e01f;packetization-mode=1")
            .replace("a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000", "a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000\r\n"
                    +"a=fmtp:100 profile-level-id=42e01f;packetization-mode=1");
}
```

We need to implement this video call feature to make it possible to call from iOS to Android and vice versa for application business.

We think WebRTC is very good technology but maybe we didn't understand enough it's specifications.

So please help us if you know any information.

We appreciate very much your help.

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the root cause is iOS capture a large video, so the solution is to scale down mediaStream on iOS and no more freeze happens.